# Image link clickable in non-white areas (excluding the background)

Tags: graphics, hyperref, pdf, urls

Consider image sample below. I'm including it using \includegraphics and I have linked it to an url using \href.

What I would like is to have it in the pdf file in such a way that the **mouse would only allow you to follow the link when passing over the grey zone and not through the white background**.

I'm using a png file with no background but with no success...

Does someone know how to do this?

Thank you so much in advance!

[image]:

Comment: The only way I can see this being possible is if you break up the shaded area into small rectangles (yes, a rectilinear object), overlap them with the shaded area *manually* and hyperlink them all. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Werner! Thanks for the answer.
It would take me forever to get it done... So i'm going to give up on this feature. Although I would really love to have it :)
Thanks anyway.

Comment: This could be done, but it would take a lot of work.  Basically one could construct a somewhat pixelated version of the image using a tikz matrix.  For a 50x50 grid using 1 letter (local) macro names would involve 50 lines of 151 characters each.  You would need both upper and lower case for the map shown.

Answer (score 6):

This was done on a smaller scale for a map of Hawaii using a 20x20 grid.  For the final version you set the opacity of the map to 1.  I find using a checkerboard background helps when aligning links to the map.  Using a `\parbox` instead of tikz `\matrix` is much faster.

I stole the map from http://www.enchantedlearning.com/usa/states/hawaii/map.GIF and converted to png.

[image: map of hawaii]

```
\documentclass[multi={tikzpicture,minipage}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\newlength{\cellwidth}
\newlength{\cellheight}

\begin{document}
\savebox{\tempbox}{\includegraphics{images/map.png}}
\setlength{\cellwidth}{\dimexpr \wd\tempbox / 20}
\setlength{\cellheight}{\dimexpr \ht\tempbox / 20}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{\mbox{\color{white}\rule{\cellwidth}{\cellheight}}}
\def\b{\rule{\cellwidth}{\cellheight}}
\def\c{\hyperlink{kauai}{\color{red}\rule{\cellwidth}{\cellheight}}}
\def\d{\hyperlink{niihau}{\color{blue}\rule{\cellwidth}{\cellheight}}}
\def\e{\hyperlink{oahu}{\color{red}\rule{\cellwidth}{\cellheight}}}
\def\f{\hyperlink{molokai}{\color{red}\rule{\cellwidth}{\cellheight}}}
\def\g{\hyperlink{lanai}{\color{red}\rule{\cellwidth}{\cellheight}}}
\def\h{\hyperlink{maui}{\color{blue}\rule{\cellwidth}{\cellheight}}}
\def\i{\hyperlink{kahoolawe}{\color{green}\rule{\cellwidth}{\cellheight}}}
\def\j{\hyperlink{hawaii}{\color{red}\rule{\cellwidth}{\cellheight}}}
\node (links) {\parbox{\wd\tempbox}{\lineskip=0pt
\a\b\a\c\c\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\\
\b\d\c\c\c\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\\
\a\d\a\c\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\\
\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\e\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\\
\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\e\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\\
\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\e\e\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\\
\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\f\f\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\\
\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\h\b\a\b\a\b\a\\
\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\g\g\h\h\b\a\b\a\b\\
\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\g\b\h\h\h\b\a\b\a\\
\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\i\i\a\b\a\b\a\b\\
\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\\
\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\j\j\b\a\b\\
\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\j\j\j\b\a\\
\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\j\j\j\j\b\\
\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\j\j\j\j\a\\
\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\j\j\j\j\b\\
\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\j\j\j\j\a\\
\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\j\j\b\a\b\\
\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\a\b\j\j\a\b\a}};
\node[opacity=.5] at (links) {\usebox{\tempbox}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{minipage}{2cm}\hypertarget{niihau}{Niihau}\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{2cm}\hypertarget{kauai}{Kauai}\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{2cm}\hypertarget{oahu}{Oahu}\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{2cm}\hypertarget{molokai}{Molokai}\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{2cm}\hypertarget{lanai}{Lanai}\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{2cm}\hypertarget{maui}{Maui}\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{2cm}\hypertarget{kahoolawe}{Kahoolawe}\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{2cm}\hypertarget{hawaii}{Hawaii}\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's really cool.

Comment: +1: Very cool indeed.