# How to make arrow tips hyperlinks in tikz-cd?

Tags: tikz-arrows

I would like to have the arrowtips in a commutative diagram link to various sections of my document. e.g.,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow[r,leftrightarrow] & B
\end{tikzcd}
\section{B to A}\label{btoa}
\section{A to B}\label{atob}
\end{document}
```

where the left arrow tip (or possibly that half of the arrow) links to the section of the document where I prove that B injects into A, and the right arrow tip/half links to the section where I prove that A injects into B.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: No and yes.  You can place an invisible link behind the arrow tip.  A rectangle would be easiest.  Somewhat related, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176280/image-link-clickable-in-non-white-areas-excluding-the-background/261071?s=1|20.5046#261071

Comment: @JohnKormylo does an overlay like that work for tikzcd? or should it first be exported as an image?

Comment: @marmot sure thing, done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along those lines?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[remember picture]
    A \arrow[r,leftrightarrow] & B
\end{tikzcd}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,opacity=0]
\node[anchor=west] at (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-1.east){\ref{btoa}};
\node[anchor=east] at (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-2.west){\ref{atob}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage
\section{B to A}\label{btoa}
\clearpage
\section{A to B}\label{atob}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you click on the left red square, you will end up in section B to A, and if you click on the right square, you will go to section A to B.

Of course, one does not have to draw these red contours, this is just for illustration. One can also move them and/or change the size. I'll be happy to do some adjustments. This here is merely to ask whether this is what you have in mind.

Comment: This is great! What parameters would change to make the links appear over the arrowheads? Also, what would change if it was a more complicated diagram? What I have in mind will probably have six arrowheads. Is it a matter of fiddling with the values that look like (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-1.east) and adding four more?

Comment: @zjs One way to move these things up is to change the anchors, e.g. `\node[anchor=south west] at (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-1.east){\ref{btoa}};
\node[anchor=south east] at (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-2.west){\ref{atob}};`. And yes, in this version you only have to repeat that game for other entries of the matrix like `\tikzcdmatrixname-1-3.east`.

Comment: [inner sep=0pt] might help a little.  Or just center the node over the tip.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've played around with it and it seems to work now for all three arrows!