# Can I make 'interactive' diagrams with Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to create diagrams, like mind maps, which expand branches when clicking on a node.
Is this something that can (and is reasonable to) be achieved with `Tikz`?
Does one need an extra package? Or it's just the wrong tool?

What I have in mind is a mind map of medium complexity, whose nodes can either expand to more pictorial information on the spot, *or* link directly to another picture or textual information.

Comment: html may be a better medium than pdf for such a thing

Comment: It should be possible to some extent using the SVG driver.  You could inject custom CSS and JavaScript into the SVG output to make it interactive when viewed in a webbrowser.  But it's not going to be easy.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98446/32995

Comment: For interaction, see hyperref, eforms and pdfcomment.  You might find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176280/image-link-clickable-in-non-white-areas-excluding-the-background/261071?r=SearchResults&s=3|9.6264#261071 amusing.