# \href is not working only with image

Tags: graphics, hyperref, hyperlink

\href{https://google.com}{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{logo.png}} - not working

\href{https://google.com}{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{logo.png}someTextHere} - working

How to make it work only with image

Comment: how are you compiling?

Comment: You could always overlay a \rule.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176280/image-link-clickable-in-non-white-areas-excluding-the-background/261071?r=SearchResults&s=5|10.7158#261071

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pdflatex/lualatex it should work. With xelatex you need \XeTeXLinkBox:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%

\begin{document}


\href{https://google.com}{\XeTeXLinkBox{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{example-image.png}}} 

\href{https://google.com}{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{example-image.png}xxx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it worked! Thank you! :)