# Can I hyperlink a specific portion of an image in Latex?

Tags: graphics, hyperref, hyperlink

I want to hyperlink some notes that I type on a page (that will result in the output pdf file) to other portions of that pdf. but in this case what I am trying to do is the following:

Add a single pdf page in my latex file (a jpeg, image, scanned textbook or any document); then, in another page type all my notes in Latex and **hyperlink** them (let's say 4 or 5 lines of text) to a **specific** portion/part of that textbook page (which is an image) which I indicate (somehow!) ..and not all of the image!

is that possible?
(I am new to Latex world! but the idea I've got is to draw a line or any symbol on the desired part of the image by using TikZ; then when needed I refer (with hyperlink) to that symbol. But can I draw on an image in latex? and can I refer or hyperlink a drawn line/symbol?)

Thank you!!

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176280/image-link-clickable-in-non-white-areas-excluding-the-background

Answer (score 1):

In the default setting the destinations use the "XYZ" view type. There they not rectangles, but an instruction where to place the  top/left corner of a page. It depends a bit on the zoom how this will be handled. As an alternative you can try FitR

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,hyperref}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%
\raisebox{5cm}[0pt][0pt]{%\hypersetup{pdfview=FitR}% option
  \hspace{-5cm}\hypertarget{image}{Here is the destination}}


\newpage

\hyperlink{image}{go to the image}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!