# Referring to subfigures without using sub caption or similar packages

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I am working on a book and I use the subcaption package to refer to some figures. However, I found that in some cases it is easier for me to just add the caption text (a), (b), etc. directly in the figure. To make things more complicated, many of these figures are created using tikz, for which I also use the tikz external (thus the figures are compiled individually. In my experience using reference within figures that are compiled using external are not showing the labels for some reason.

Because of all this, the problem is that now it's hard to refer to subfigures. I managed to use the `\ref` and `\hyperref` commands as follows:

```
Figure~\ref{fig:some_figure}\hyperref[fig:some_figure]{a}
```

Still, this solution isn't perfect because when I hover over I have two separate hyperlinks. Is there a simpler, better way to accomplish what I want without using subacaption or similar packages?

Perhaps if there is a macro that I can use to obtain the figure number from a figure label, then I could use attach a label to the text (a) in the figure caption and then refer to it like:

```
Figure~\hyperref[fig:some_figure_a]{\getFigureNumber{fig:some_figure}a}
```

Comment: Externalize inputs the PDF using \includegraphics, which loses the anchor points.

Comment: If `\ref{fig:some_figure}\hyperref[fig:some_figure]{a}` works in your situation, you could get one link with `\hyperref[fig:some_figure]{\ref*{fig:some_figure}a}`. But, without a MWE, that's just a guess.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176280/image-link-clickable-in-non-white-areas-excluding-the-background/261071?r=SearchResults&s=1|40.8095#261071

Answer (score 1):

I use `\subfig`, `\subcaption` packages when I have multiple subfigures in my write-up. I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but please see below my approach. I used the `latex` .svg.png file as a reference picture (found online).

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\subfloat[Sample]{\label{a}\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{LaTeX_logo.svg.png}}\hfill
\subfloat[Sample]{\label{b}\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{LaTeX_logo.svg.png}}\hfill
\subfloat[Sample]{\label{c}\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{LaTeX_logo.svg.png}}\hfill
\subfloat[Sample]{\label{d}\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{LaTeX_logo.svg.png}}
\caption{Sample Output.}
\end{figure}

\vspace{5em}
\huge Figures~\ref{a} to~\ref{d} are shown above. %Used \huge just for illustration purpose. 

\end{document}
```

I get:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The subcaption package documentation contains a section "Captions inside sub-figures" regarding this topic. Particularly the sub-sections "Referencing sub-figures without sub-captions" and "Using the tikz package" might be of interest for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `\phantomlabel` (of package `subcaption`) and then combined with `Figure~\hyperref[fig:some_figure_a]{\ref{fig:some_figure}a}` may do what you want.