# Tikz button CLICK color and CLICK shape in Adobe Reader

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, pdf, tikz-shape, href

I would like to control the click color and click shape of the following tikz button with rounded corners that I created. When I download the PDF (generated by pdflatex) into Adobe Reader and click on the button, the button turns bright yellow and black rectangular corners are added to the button. Is there a way in tikz and or LaTeX to modify these effects?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, shapes, automata, backgrounds, positioning, shadows, patterns, calc, arrows.meta, shapes.geometric, decorations.shapes, decorations.fractals, decorations.markings, decorations.pathmorphing}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\tikzset{
    hyperlink node/.style={
        alias=sourcenode,
        append after command={
            let \n0={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}},
                \n1={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}},
                \p1=([shift={(\n0, -\n1)}] sourcenode.north west),
                \p2=([shift={(-\n0, \n1)}] sourcenode.south east),
                \n2={\x2-\x1},
                \n3={\y1-\y2} in
            node [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=north west, at=(\p1)] {\hyperlink{#1}{\XeTeXLinkBox{\phantom{\rule{\n2}{\n3}}}}}
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, button/.style={fit={(0cm,0cm) (6.3cm,1.5cm)}, fill=blue, draw=none, drop shadow, text=white, rounded corners=.75cm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, label=center:\textcolor{white}{\huge\textsc{Read Me}}}]
  \node[button, hyperlink node=bottom] at (0cm,0cm) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vfill
\hypertarget{bottom}{{Bottom of Page}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: well the reader simply inverts the color, with text you would get white on black. It is possible to create custom pushbuttons see the document l3pdffield-pushbutton, but this involves more work.

Comment: You should also check out the eforms package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for this information Ulrike! I looked at that document a little, although it is above my head.  However, I did notice this statement: "This key sets the normal appearance, the rollover appearance (when the mouse hovers over the push button) and the down appearance (when the mouse clicks). They take as a value ⟨appearance name⟩ and expect that one form Xobjects with this name has been created before. It depends on the PDF viewer if such appearances are shown. Adobe reader for example ignores the down appearance."  I am creating for Adobe since it offers liquid mode.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you for  this info!  I looked at the eforms package manual a bit.  It looks very comprehensive and customizable.  It wasn't apparent to me that  the shape of the button can easily be  modified unless I was missing something.  I imagine it is somehow possible perhaps by bringing in a shape from tikz?

Comment: You can also place a rectangular hyperref link under a tikz shape.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176280/image-link-clickable-in-non-white-areas-excluding-the-background